# What is wrong with these delimiters?

Tags: php, preg-match

For this code:

```
{
    $params = explode("/\n/", $params);                 
    $return = array();

    foreach($params as $param) {
        if (preg_match($key, $param)) {
            $return[] = $param;
        }
    }
    return implode("/\n/", $return);
}
```

I get "Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash"

Can someone tell me what I'm missing or need to change? Thank you.

Some more info, this was changed from:

```
/**
 * Filter (remove) a parameter from a parameter string
 * @return string Filtered parameter String
 * @param object $params
 * @param object $key
 */
function filterParams($params, $key)
{
    $params = explode("\n", $params);                   
    $return = array();

    foreach($params as $param) {
        if (eregi($key, $param)) {
            $return[] = $param;
        }
    }
    return implode("\n", $return);
}
/**
 * Return the JCE Editor's parameters
 *
 * @return object
*/
```

because the "ereg" error w/PHP 5.3 upgrade. I changed it in several other places that returned error codes, per information on this site, and added the front slashes and the errors went away everywhere but here. Let me add that I am not a programmer, just a website manager. I am out of my element here.

Comment: What's in `$key`?

Comment: sidenote, `explode` doesn't use regex

Comment: Maybe use preg_split("/\n/", $params) would be appropriate here.

Comment: that gave me this error: preg_split() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Comment: Now your explode function is correct since $params is a string. By the way, can you show us what's in key so we'll be able to see precisely what cause you the error.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between how `ereg-*` functions handle regular expressions and how `preg_*` functions handle them. Basically, you need to have some `not alphanumeric or backslash` character at both ends to make the function work.

Try this:

```
$key = '/' . $key . '/';
// or $key = '#' . $key . '#';
// or $key = '@' . $key . '@';
// etc.

// later
if (preg_match($key, $param)) {
    $return[] = $param;
}
```

You will need to [escape that key](https://www.php.net/preg_quote), but this should give you a start.

Also, as a note, I don't think you mean `/\n/`. You should return to `\n`. The difference: the first one matches this string:

```
foo/
/bar
```

While the second matches this string

```
foo
bar
```

Comment: I tried that and now I am getting a different error message that references another file:
PHP Error Message: WARNINGcall_user_func_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string givenError"

Comment: If I remove the front slashes, the error message repeats about 100 times. With the front slashes in, it only repeats twice.